# Nuxt PWA isn't loading offline with workbox

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have set up nuxt pwa module to work with nuxt firebase auth and it works fine, plus I added icon and manifest to take advantage from the downloadable app. The issue is I must be doing something wrong with workbox because my app won't load if you are offline. Default browser offline message will show up. My workbox config is

```
workbox: {
     runtimeCaching: [{
       urlPattern: 'https://twitch-toc.now.sh/.*',
       handler: 'cacheFirst',
       method: 'GET',
       strategyOptions: {
         networkTimeoutSeconds: 20,
         cacheName: 'api-cache',
         cacheableResponse: {
           statuses: [0, 200]
         }
       }
     }
     ],
     importScripts: [
       // ...
       '/firebase-auth-sw.js'
     ],
     // by default the workbox module will not install the service worker in dev environment to avoid conflicts with HMR
     // only set this true for testing and remember to always clear your browser cache in development
     // dev: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
   }
```

Please let me know what I'm missing because I can't find any documentation or guides on how to make it work.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix to this? Care to share?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the exact same problem for months and now I found that the firebase sw is messing with the default workbox sw. If you comment the imporscripts line as well as the firebase module import and config it will work just fine. Now I'm trying to find a workaround in order to not get rid of firebase since it makes auth so much easier, although making custom made Oauth might be much cheaper.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer, it reads more like a comment. The answer feature should be used only to leave answers to the question, and not for comments. The reason for this is that if someone leaves a non-answer as an answer it causes the question to appear to have already been answered and lowers the chances of that question getting a good answer.